# React Navigation 5: Fixing headerRight Spacing

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation-v5

**This is what my header looks like now:**

[image: current header]

**And this is what I am trying to achieve:**

[image: wanted header]

**Code snippet:**

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="MenuRoute">
        <Stack.Screen
          name={'MenuRoute'}
          component={Menu}
          options={({navigation, route}) => ({
            headerTitle: () => (
              <Text
                style={{
                  ...styles.headerTitle,
                }}>
                <Translatable value="Menu" />
              </Text>
            ),
            headerLeft: () => <AuthMenuPicker {...navigation} {...route} />,
            headerRight: () => (
              <View style={styles.row}>
                <FacebookButton {...navigation} {...route}/>
                <LanguagePicker />
              </View>
            ),
            headerStyle,
          })}
        />

        .....
        .....
        .....

</Stack.Navigator>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  }
});
```

> How can I move the Facebook Logo towards the right side (as shown in the image)?
>
> I have tried `marginLeft` and `paddingLeft` but nothing seems to do the trick.

All help would be appreciated as I am new with this issue and with react navigation 5 in general.

**UPDATE#1:**

**Added `borderWidth:1` and `borderColor: 'red'` to clearly show the `headerLeft` area:**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor:  'red',
  }
});
```

[image: update header]

**UPDATE#2 - Added component code snippets:**

**Code Snippet (`FacebookButton` component):**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import {FACEBOOK} from '../constants';

class FacebookButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() { }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Button
                    //onPress={() => alert()}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.props.navigate(
                            'FacebookMenuWebviewRoute',
                            {
                                url: FACEBOOK.FACEBOOK_PAGE,
                            },
                        );
                    }}
                >
                    <Entypo
                        name="facebook"
                        size={this.props.iconSize || 25}
                        style={{ ...styles.icon, ...this.props.iconStyle }}
                    />
                </Button>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    icon: {
        color: 'white',
    },
});

export default FacebookButton;
```

**Code snippet (`LanguagePicker` component):**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
    import {Menu, Button, withTheme} from 'react-native-paper';
    import Fontisto from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto';
    import {IntlContext} from '../utility/context/Internationalization';
    
    class LanguagePicker extends Component {

      ...
      ...
      ...
    
      renderPicker() {
        return (
          <IntlContext.Consumer>
            {(context) => {
              return (
                <Menu
                  visible={this.state.showMenu}
                  onDismiss={() => this.showMenu(false)}
                  anchor={
                    <Button
                      onPress={() => this.showMenu(true)}
                      style={{
                        ...styles.menuButton,
                        ...this.props.menuButtonStyle,
                      }}>
                      <Fontisto
                        name="earth"
                        size={this.props.iconSize || 25}
                        style={{...styles.icon, ...this.props.iconStyle}}
                      />
                    </Button>
                  }>
                  {this.renderPickerItems(context)}
                </Menu>
              );
            }}
          </IntlContext.Consumer>
        );
      }
    
      render() {
        return <>{this.renderPicker()}</>;
      }
    }
    
    export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      menuButton: {},
      icon: {
        color: 'white',
      },
    });
    
    export default withTheme(LanguagePicker);
```

Comment: Can you check the space allocation using something like dev tools and post that image?

Comment: Do you have any styles in FacebookButton or LanguagePicker ?

Comment: @theWellHopeErr I am not familiar with dev tools but I have added an image that shows the space allocation. Hope this is something similar to what you asked for.

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan not much styling. Only have added color for the different icons. I have added code snippets for both the components.

Comment: i tried with two icons and didnt have any issue, but as you are using several wrappers you will have to check those

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan Thank you. I have just solved the issue by removing `Button` and using `TouchableOpacity` in the `FacebookButton` component. I was using `Button` from `react-native-paper` which was wrapped around the Facebook icon and it had its own fixed area.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @GuruparanGiritharan for pointing out about the wrappers.

**Solution:**

**Code snippet `FacebookButton` component:**

```
 <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}
          onPress={() => { ... }
    >
              <Entypo
                 name="facebook"
                 size={this.props.iconSize || 25}
                 style={{ ...styles.icon, ...this.props.iconStyle }}
              />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**New Header:**

[image: new header]

**Explanation:**

I was using `Button` component from `react-native-paper` and the component had its own fixed spacing. This caused the Facebook icon to be *too* spaced out.

Thus, removing the `Button` component and simply adding `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native` helped to reduce the space between the two icons on the header.